# JWT Authentication in ditto

Tags: authentication, jwt, eclipse-ditto, ditto, eclipse-digital-twin

I have question on configuring JWT authentication in ditto. don't know on which config file I have to do and what I have to do? will give me the steps how to do it? with one example.

I tried basic authentication in ditto but now I need to know steps of JWT authentication in ditto with one example.